# 'this.variable' doesn't change?

Tags: javascript

I create a bunch of new objects from function below. Then, from within a loop, I loop through each one and call methods toggleValid() and toggleErrMsg(). In toggleErrMsg(), it's supposed to change value of the object.errMsgStatus to true if it's false, but it doesn't. Why?

```
  function InputField(field, cssTarget, value, errMsg, validator) {
    var self = this;
    this.field = field,
    this.cssTarget = cssTarget,
    this.value = value,
    this.valid = false,
    this.errMsg = errMsg,
    this.errMsgStatus = false,
    this.validator = validator,
    this.toggleErrMsg = function() {
        if(self.valid === false && self.errMsgStatus === false) {
            self.errMsgStatus = true;
            renderValidationError(self, false);
        } else {
            self.errMsgStatus = false;
            renderValidationError(self, true);
        }
    }
    this.toggleValid = function() {
        self.validator();
        if(!self.valid) {
            self.cssTarget().addClass("inputInvalid");
        } else {
            self.cssTarget().removeClass("inputInvalid");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: how is this constructor function initialized and how are those methods called?

Answer (score 0):

This will probably have to do with the way you initialiaze InputField.
As no code is provided yet you are probably doing

```
var inputField = InputField();
```

while it should be

```
var inputField = new InputField();
```

Answer (score -2):

try

```
  function InputField(field, cssTarget, value, errMsg, validator) {
    var self = this;
    self.field = field,
    self.cssTarget = cssTarget,
    self.value = value,
    self.valid = false,
    self.errMsg = errMsg,
    self.errMsgStatus = false,
    self.validator = validator,
    this.toggleErrMsg = function() {
        if(self.valid === false && self.errMsgStatus === false) {
            self.errMsgStatus = true;
            renderValidationError(self, false);
        } else {
            self.errMsgStatus = false;
            renderValidationError(self, true);
        }
    }
    this.toggleValid = function() {
        self.validator();
        if(!self.valid) {
            self.cssTarget().addClass("inputInvalid");
        } else {
            self.cssTarget().removeClass("inputInvalid");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: it is incorrect, you override outer scope self variable which is intended to be that way

Comment: Your second edit does not change anything from OPs question. Asigning to this and self in that context is the same